# Unexpected Behaviour of inherited static member

Tags: java, inheritance, static, overriding, hide

I was just playing around with `static` and inheritance to see what can and cannot be done. I have read before, that static methods cannot be overwritten, they can simply be hidden. That is why I tried to see what applies to static members. Here is some simple Test code:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public static String x;
    { x = "In ParentClass"; }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    { x = "In ChildClass"; }
}
```

Now when I printed x called from objects, everything went as expected:

```
ParentClass parentClassReference = new ParentClass();
System.out.println(parentClassReference.x); // prints: "In ParentClass"

parentClassReference = new ChildClass();
System.out.println(parentClassReference.x); // prints: "In ChildClass"
```

Even the trivial call to x from a child class object:

```
ChildClass childClassReference = new ChildClass();
System.out.println(childClassReference.x); // prints: "In ChildClass"
```

Now, when I call the static member, like it is supposed to be done, it gets weird:

```
System.out.println(ChildClass.x); // prints: "In ChildClass" (Ok, so far.)
System.out.println(ParentClass.x); // prints: "In ChildClass" (This is unexpected.)
```

I have no explanation for this behaviour. In the context of [Overriding vs. Hiding (Code Ranch)](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OverridingVsHiding) It seemed more likely that the calls through objects shouldn't work as expected, but the calls through class names should.

I am confused. Who can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is *very* strange... but the results are exactly as I'd expect.

You need to understand three things:

- There's only *one* `x` variable here. Whether you reference it as `ChildClass.x` or `ParentClass.x`, it's the same variable
- When you refer to a static member *via a reference*, the compiler just translates it to a static reference, without looking at the value of the reference at all. So `childClassReference.x` is equivalent to `ChildClass.x`, which is actually compiled as `ParentClass.x`. Good IDEs will warn you of this sort of thing - it produced confusing code.
- The code you've written which *sets* the value of `x` is only executed based on a constructor call. Basically it's equivalent to:

  ```
  public class ParentClass {
      public static String x;
      public ParentClass() {
          x = "In ParentClass";
      }
  }

  public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
      public ChildClass() {
          x = "In ChildClass";
      }
  }
  ```

Fundamentally, you shouldn't be trying to achieve any kind of polymorphism through static members. It doesn't work, and attempts to fake it will not end happily.

Comment: Ok, now I see through the construct I had in mind. My IDE did in fact warn me about it, but as I said: I was playing around to see what happens.

Comment: +1 IMHO its never a good idea to set static fields in a constructor (or initialiser block)